# SQL Server - how to listen for table changes

Tags: sql-server, listen

In PostgreSQL, I can add a trigger that performs

```sql
PERFORM pg_notify('table', 'some data');
```

to all clients that have performed

```sql
LISTEN table;
```

Is it possible to do something like that in SQL Server?

Comment: looks like Service Broker functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used SqlTableDependency ([Github link](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency)) which effectively removes the necessity for writing additional code in the .NET application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers to do this
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-trigger-student-database/amp/

Comment: Triggers are used for "listening" for changes within the database itself. I stated I need a way for my database to let anyone outside of it (e.g an application) know about the changes. I think the example I provided is clear enough for that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).